# Retrofit 2.3.0 CallAdapter.Factory

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a base `APIResult` which serves the purpose of checking for certain data being returned by the API. I am trying to create a `CustomCall` object that will check for this data whenever an API is being fired but I am confused as to how I should do it. This is what I have:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public CallAdapter<?, ?> get(@NonNull final Type returnType,
                             @NonNull final Annotation[] annotations,
                             @NonNull final Retrofit retrofit) {
    final Type responseType = getParameterUpperBound(0, (ParameterizedType) returnType);

    return new CallAdapter<Object, CustomCall<? extends APIResult>>() { // Is this correct?!

        @Override
        public Type responseType() {
            return responseType;
        }

        @Override
        public CustomCall<? extends APIResult> adapt(@NonNull Call<Object> call) {
            // How/what do I return here exactly?
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Here is an example [call adapter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/ErrorHandlingAdapter.java)

Comment: @LordRaydenMK I am porting that code over but can't help but think that it's immensely overkill for what I want. All I require is to check for 1 object in the response to come back and save it to Realm. That's pretty much it.